# C++ Destructors: Undefined Behaviour or not?

Tags: c++, destructor

Consider the following piece of code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class A
{
    private:
        char name[10];

    public:
        A() { }
        A(const char *str)
        {
            strcpy(name, str);
            std::cout<<name<<" constructed"<<endl; 
        }
        ~A()
        {
           std::cout<<name<<" destructed"<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
   A a("a");
   A b("b");
   return 0;
}
```

O/P of the following programs comes out to be:

```
a constructed
b constructed
b destructed
a destructed
```

The only explanation I have for the above code is that since `b` was created after `a`, it should be stored above `a` in the stack. Now when the main finishes, `b` was poped out first and then `a`, hence its destructor got called first and then of `a`'s.

My question is: Am I correct in thinking so or the above is an undefined behavior and may varies from compiler to compiler?

Comment: If it wasn't this way, and `b` here stored a reference to `a`, accessing that `a` on b's destructor would lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: I also think you're confusing undefined behavior with unspecified behavior.

Comment: It is refered to as "the stack" for this reason reason. First in, last out.

Comment: @juan Actually the call stack conceptually stores *stack frames* (or “activation records”). *Those* are handled in LIFO manner, not necessarily the elements of a single stack frame.

Comment: @KonradRudolph interesting. Do you have an example of when it would make sense for the elements of a stack frame not to be handled LIFO?

Comment: @juan No, since lifetime constraints still matter (see mfontanini’s comment above). I just think that this is coincidental and unrelated to the call stack being a stack. Or rather, it’s a different layer of abstraction, even though it makes of course sense from a processor architecture implementation point of view (it’s a very efficient way of handling storage).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not vary, objects in *automatic memory* (stack) are destructed in reverse order in which they are created. It's fully specified by the standard.

**C++03 15.2. Constructors and destructors**

> 1. [...] The automatic objects are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their construction.

Comment: any specific reason for destroying them in reverse order? Does C++ standards says so?

Comment: @RaviGupta yes, the standard says so.

Comment: Also imagine case, when you create object and pass pointer or reference to it to next object. If destroy order was undefined or exactly the same as construction, second object would have invalid pointer or reference, which would complicate programming.

Comment: @greg: i got it what you are trying saying but to make things more clear can you provide an example.

Comment: Note that temporaries created in the evaluation of an expression obeys the same rules: their creation might not obey any specific order (the order of evaluation of a function's arguments is not specified) but they will be destroyed in the reverse order of their construction nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Here is why order of destruction matters (and should be reversed creation order)

```
class Foo
{
public:
  void foo() { /* ... */ }
};

class Bar
{
public:
   Bar(Foo const & foo) foo(foo) {}
   virtual ~Bar() { this->foo.foo(); }

   Foo const & foo;
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  Bar bar(foo);
  // if foo gets destroyed before bar, then bar will call method foo() on invalid reference in its destructor
  // it is much more convenient to have bar destroyed before foo in such cases
}
```